# Is L-Elf clairvoyant?

Tags: valvrave-the-liberator

In the show **Valvrave the Liberator**, there's a secret agent of the Dorssian military named "L-elf Karlstein", who seemed to belong to a group of other "gifted" members of the Dorssian military. L-Elf seems to be able to see certain sequences of events in the future and be able to predict them (for example, to Haruto) in an almost Nostradamian way, yet during combat, he can clearly strategize a winning plan and even calculate the number of total loses correctly.

Is L-Elf clairvoyant with some sort of super-human powers? Or is he just really, *really*, smart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L-Elf is not clairvoyant, he is just highly intelligent. He takes what he knows about the people around him as well as what he knows about the enemy so that he can predict the movements of what will or what can happen. If there is someone he does not know or understand his calculations are seen as false predictions. I believe it was episodes 3 and 4 of the first season that proved that he was not clairvoyant. If you watch the series over again with that in mind, you will see that everything he says is based on what he plans, with some variations.

At the end of the first season of the series Cain clearly states that "L-Elf, I trained you well. That is how I can predict your movements now."